# Wordpress: One Writer Node and a Few Reader Nodes Behind a Load Balancer. Can't Direct the Login to JUST the Writer Node

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, high-availability

I am stuck between AWS and Wordpress. I've worked my way though a tutorial as an exercise, and I am pretty sure that the tutorial has some failed logic in it. If you have the time, here's the setup. It's supposed to work like this.

You have an EC2 instance with your WP installation on it. We will call this the writer node. It sits outside of the load balancer.

The database is sitting on an RDS instance.

You then have an Application Load Balancer that loads EC2 instances with their own WP installations that also read from the RDS instance.

That's the idea. You make all your posts to the writer, which is out of the view of public-user reads. Public-users are directed via Route 53 to the ALB.

Holding this together is S3 and crontab. The writer node writes the contents of the html folder to an S3 bucket, and the contents of the uploads folder to another bucket that is read by a Cloudfront distribution.

The EC2 WP instances behind the ALB check those to buckets for changes every minute to make sure that they're up-to-date. (I should note that I created an AMI from the write node for the auto scaling group EC2s behind the ALB with the crontab adjusted for reading FROM S3- not writing to S3).

So far so good. Data updates and flows in the correct direction from the writer, which writes to the RDS database AND writes to S3, while the readers read from the RDS db and S3. AWS is functioning as it should. HOWEVER, the issue with this tutorial is Wordpress- specifically, how to log into the wp-admin page of the write node EC2?? On the surface, it seems easy.

This tutorial has you create and A/Alias record for yoursite.com to point to the DNS address of the Application Load Balancer. Then it tells you to create another A record named write.yoursite.com and point that to the public IP address of your write node/EC2. That sounds logical, but if you know Wordpress, you may know what the problem is (and hopefully know the answer!).

So, when you go to yoursite.com/wp-admin, it directs you to one of the EC2s behind the ALB.

If you go to write.yoursite.com/wp-admin, it directs you to the write node for a hot second, then Wordpress pushes you to one of the EC2s behind the ALB.

In other words, you have to choose one or the other in the Wordpress database, right? Either you get the writer node, and everything is fine but you basically don't use the load balancer and auto scaling group, or you get the load balancer and autoscaling group, but as soon as you upload an image or plugin, the crontab setting overwrites it, deleting it, because it's a one-way read from S3 to the reader nodes. They weren't planning on Wordpress undoing what Route53 is trying to accomplish.

So, their tutorial is incorrect? Yes?

What I need is for Route 53 to actually be able to direct write.yoursite.com to the IP of the write node, and all the regular yoursite.com read traffic to the ALB for the auto scaling group EC2s to take care of business.

Does anyone know if it's even *possible* to set up a rule like that somewhere in the Wordpress installation? Can you split traffic like that at the Wordpress level? Is there a path-based routing function that you can turn on in Wordpress? I've been scouring the internet and found a ton of posts from people doing similar things with high availability WP installations, but either the posts are 10 years old or there were no definitive answers. I've also been trying to get someone at the company that posted the tutorial to respond, but so far no luck.

Thank you in advance for any ideas! I would really like to put this to rest.

-Phil

Comment: Whoever gave my post a minus one, would you care to comment on the post?

Comment: Nobody? Well, in the meantime, I figured it out. There are quite a few hoops to jump though, but it is possible. I'll post again as soon as I am sure that it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll post my own answer then LOL.

The issue is the WordPress database. It always stores absolute file path URLS. All traffic is directed to the main URL, which in this case, is actually pointing to all of the (what I am calling) read-node servers behind the load balancer.

So, to fix this you have to install a WordPress plug that will strip the absolute file paths from the database thus leaving everything with a relative path. There are plugins out there that seem to strip the absolute file paths for the browser side of things but not IN the database itself, so be aware of that. I used a plugin called "Make Paths Relative" by Yas Global that indeed alters the database URLs.

Next, I added this bit of code to the wp-config.php file:

define(‘WP_HOME’, ‘http://’.$_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’].’/’);

define(‘WP_SITEURL’, ‘http://’.$_SERVER[‘HTTP_HOST’].’/’)

NOW you can have admin.yoursite.com point to a specific server and yoursite.com point to another server or load balancer that all share the same WordPress installation as noted above without having to resort to AWS EFS (if you're trying to save money).